# AChartEngine - how to create plot with vertical lines to scatter (residuals)

Tags: android, regression, achartengine, scatter-plot, line-plot

In AChartEngine, how would one create a line plot with scatter residuals -- i.e. using vertical lines to connect the regression line to the scatter plot?

Or, for that matter, is there another Android charting library that can do this?

This is the behavior I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK that library doesn't give that. For your question, if there's other library: I generally prefer [afreechart](https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/) library, Which, has a full section dedicated to scatter charts (http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/index.html -> "Scatter charts" heading)

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I don't see this specific type of scatter chart in the screenshots.  Do you know if it's supported?  Also, do they support combined scatter/line plots?

Comment: Don't know if there's a specific. Regarding combined charts - I think they support it.